# Minimum Eigenvalue of the Rank One update to a Positive Semi-Definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a $N\times N$ positive semi-definite hermitian matrix. Let $\mathbf{b}$ be a $N\times 1$ complex vector. For any given constant $t$, I interested in the minimum eigenvalue of the matrix $\mathbf{A}+t\cdot\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^H$. Is there a closed form solution for this? If not, Can we come up with a simple iterative algorithm for the the same? Can you point me to some relevant references?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\chi_A$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Here $\chi_{A+tbb^H}(x)=\chi_A(x)+tP_{n-1}(x)$ where $P_{n-1}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. Thus, to obtain $\chi_{A+tbb^H}$, it is sufficient to calculate $\chi_A$ and $\chi_{A+bb^H}$. If you want a numerical approximation, then the complexity of the previous calculation is $O(n^3)$. Finally, for each fixed $t$, the problem is reduced to find the minimum root of a polynomial, that is well-known.